# com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL , 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, google-app-engine, netbeans

When click the netbeans project to `Deploy to Google App Engine` these are the messages shown on the Google App Deployment console :

```
May 28, 2012 4:22:06 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed /home/non-admin/NetBeansProjects/Guestbook/build/web/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
May 28, 2012 4:22:06 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed /home/non-admin/NetBeansProjects/Guestbook/build/web/WEB-INF/web.xml
Beginning server interaction for ...
Password for suhailgupta03@gmail.com: 
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL:  https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=&version=1&
400 Bad Request
app_id GET query string parameter must be supplied.

Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/getresourcelimits?app_id=&version=1&
400 Bad Request
app_id GET query string parameter must be supplied.

Please see the logs [/tmp/appcfg5900452573644976629.log] for further information.
```

I don't know the reason why do i get this. [Link for the /tmp/appcfg5900452573644976629.log](http://suhail3.my3gb.com/appcfg5900452573644976629.log)

What could be the reason ? *I have checked that application has interacted successfully with google. i.e email and passwords match*

In case,

*appengine-web.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
<application></application>
<version>1</version>

<system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
</system-properties>

<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

</appengine-web-app>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<application></application>` tag is empty.

How should AppEngine know where to put your application without that?

You have to insert an application ID in there that you previously registered on http://appengine.google.com.

Comment: I had same issue and I also put that app id between <application></application>  still same problem  please help

Comment: Please open a new question and I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1):

check if all google app engine libraries are there. This was my problem. It was working locally though.

Answer (score 1):

This error can also happen if you've given the full host name instead of just the app ID.

**Wrong:**

```
<application>myappid.appspot.com</application>
```

**Right:**

```
<application>myappid</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution to this can be like, as it worked for me:

properties:

```
<properties>    
        <appengine.app.version>10</appengine.app.version>       
        <appengine.target.version>1.8.7</appengine.target.version>      
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

configuration:

```
<configuration>                             
        <version>${appengine.app.version}</version>                        
</configuration>
```

In **configuration** label, write version as that in **properties** label as above.
Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is the problem rises when u abort the application while deploying so change the version of the application nor rollback the url

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:** This happens when you had changed your application name in "build.properties" file but its not updated into "appengine-web.xml" file.

**Solution:** Please go ahead and change application name in "appengine-web.xml" manually.

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>photofeed-lab2</application>
  <version>1</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
</appengine-web-app>
```